# Exploding a list of dictionaries in pandas to multiple rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with Shopify's Order API and I receive the following responses, which currently sit in a dataframe (very simplified).

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| order_id | name      | item_order                                                                  |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 123      |  Jon Doe  | [{'id':789,'price':40.0,'sku':'HAT'},{'id':790,'price':41.0,'sku':'SHIRT'}] |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 122      | Jonah Doe |                    [{'id':553,'price':20.0,'sku':'CAP'}]                    |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          |           |                                                                             |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to explode item_order, so we get something closer to the below:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+
| order_id | name      | item_order.id | item_order.price | item_order.sku |
+----------+-----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+
| 123      |  Jon Doe  | 789           | 40.0             | HAT            |
+----------+-----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+
| 123      | Jon Doe   | 790           | 41.0             | SHIRT          |
+----------+-----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+
| 122      | Jonah Doe | 553           | 20               | CAP            |
+----------+-----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = df.explode('item_order').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('item_order')))
```

Answer (score 1):

First `explode` and then `agg(pd.Series)`:

```
new_df = df.explode('item_order')
new_df[['item_order.id', 'item_order.price', 'item_order.sku']] = ( new_df['item_order'].
                                                              agg(pd.Series) )
```